# Micro is not recognised as HID device

Tags: arduino-micro, windows

Being a completely noob with Arduino (but not with coding though) I'm trying to create a simple buttonbox with a Micro unit.

For now, I can not figure out what should I do to make my Windows 10 recognize the Arduino as a HID device (joystick actually). What did I miss?

Comment: How should we be able to tell you, what you missed? You didn't give us any information at all. Provide the code, that you use. Also: Have you tried the examples from the Arduino IDE? For me they worked pretty well

Comment: @chrisl, Sorry, I thought it lays beyond arduino coding. I use a pretty simple matrix solution with Keyboard.h library. It works ok: all buttons are being recognized correctly (I use println for debug). Next thing I need is to make Win see the arduino as game controller. But no new devices are found in device list, no any devices available to add and so on. Should I make some extra steps to achieve that? As I know Micro board has a sort of HID controller in it's chip (sorry for missnaming if any) so it should be recognized in Windows by default. Should I use some extra library or something?

Comment: I don't quite understand, what you are trying to achieve. With the `Keyboard` library, the Micro will behave like a keyboard, which is by definition a HID device. I don't understand, where you mean it should appear in Windows and why? Gamecontrollers and keyboards are both HID devices, but they are not the same

Comment: this box should be a gamecontroller at the end. I sow a bunch of guides about how to make it and there no any steps described how to _make Windows work with arduino as a game controller_. So I have a _gamepad_ now, what should I do to make Windows work with it when connected in USB?

Comment: As I wrote, Windows already works with it, treating it like a keyboard (as you told the Micro to behave like one). Generally Windows doesn't do much here. I guess you want, that it identifies itself as game controller. Then you cannot use the Keyboard library. Have you tried the `Joystick` library?

Comment: My bad. I mean I use Keypad.h not Keyboard.h Anyway, If I need Windows to see it as a game controller I have to use **Joystick** library https://github.com/MHeironimus/ArduinoJoystickLibrary, correct?

Comment: I think yes, though I haven't used it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Joystick ([github.com/MHeironimus/ArduinoJoystickLibrary](https://github.com/MHeironimus/ArduinoJoystickLibrary)) lib did the job. @chrisl, thx for the patience.